# Facebook Like Button with NextGen Gallery

Tags: plugins, facebook

i'm following this tutorial: http://itc.webmaasters.com/nextgen-gallery-with-facebook-and-twitter-wordpress-tutorial-or-hack/ for implement Facebook Like Button on this plugin.

It's working very well, but if you like the picture, this "like" does not appear in your timeline on facebook. On the photo you see the "countdown" of likes, but it not appearing on timeline...

Any script that is missing so there is your "like"?

Comment: you have to insert meta tags for facebook in your header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not use this plugin ? [NextGEN Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-facebook/)

Adds Facebook HTML meta tags to webpage headers, including featured images. Also includes optional Like and Send Facebook buttons.

Comment: this Plugin only add "Like Button" on pages and posts, and i want to add the "like" on every photo of my gallery...

Comment: i dont think it´s possible... the like is made to like/share a post/page... it need the extra infos in header to work correctly... maybe if you can transform your lightbox gallery in iframes popup (with specific header for every image)...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
you need the Open Graph Tags type: <meta property="og:tag name" content="tag value"/>

Comment: i success add the button count on every photo, and the count works well. The only problem, thats the "Like" is not appearing under my Facebook Timeline.

Comment: your FB app is able to post on timeline ?

Comment: can you tell me where i can see this options? See my example post where you can see the images, click on them and you can see the "Like Button": http://www.djrenato.com.br/site/?p=3163.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/apps in your app setting page in facebook

Comment: yeah.. but i can't see any option with these terms..

Comment: in the open graph -> actions, objects...
you need to read the documentation of facebook

Comment: but i think it´s not a problem in your app... it´s like i said: you need the Open Graph Tags type: <meta property="og:tag name" content="tag value"/> in your page header

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.djrenato.com.br%2Fsite%2F%3Fp%3D3163

use the url debbuger of facebook...